# MySQL DateTime Format usage example?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Hi i created user registration form in PHP and i need to add milliseconds to registration time. php on server is v 5.2.14 so it does not allow milliseconds in date format.

How can i create field in mysql database that will auto print current date, time including milliseconds to any row i add.

Comment: jus for info : mysql itself didn't support milli or makro second in date format. it is a bug, http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8523

Answer (score 2):

Use of `date()` to format, along with `microtime()` should yield the result you want. This is from the actual PHP docs user comments:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
<?php
function udate($format, $utimestamp = null)
{
    if (is_null($utimestamp))
        $utimestamp = microtime(true);

    $timestamp = floor($utimestamp);
    $milliseconds = round(($utimestamp - $timestamp) * 1000000);

    return date(preg_replace('`(?<!\\\\)u`', $milliseconds, $format), $timestamp);
}

echo udate('H:i:s.u'); // 19:40:56.78128
echo udate('H:i:s.u', 654532123.04546); // 16:28:43.45460
?>
```

**Update:**

To use in MySQL, just insert into any column with a datetime format. If you want to make it even simpler, set up the table to auto-populate on insert and update and you won't have to control this from the application.